# Get the new url opened

Tags: php, html, url, selenium, rows

I am fairly new to php. I have a table displayed in my page. The rowid is not displayed and it is a number that gets automatically incremented every time a row is added. (You do not do know what is the row id that is displayed on top). When I click on that row, it opens a new page like (www.newpage.com/newpage/rowid). 
If i use inspect element, I can see the rowid as

My question is

1. Is there any way to retrieve the rowid value from the HTML ? since it is a hidden field, will the selenium driver be able to understand it
2. If step1 is not an option, is there a way to capture the url name that is displayed when the new page opens?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the usual approach would be to retrieve it from the url. `newpage?rowid=7` then `$_GET['rowid']` or similar

Comment: www.newpage.com/newpage/rowid - is `rowid` a get variable and you're using .htaccess to rewrite urls? Or its an actual html page?

Comment: $url = $this->webDriver->getCurrentURL();

Simple URL pickup :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the html form method your using is GET, then you can do what Dagon suggested in the comments...Something like this? - `$rowid = $_GET['rowid']`

Answer (score 0):

## "How can I retrieve my rowID value from the HTML?"

Since you didn't provide any markup, I'm going to assume the rowID is stored in the `name:` attribute.

For example: `<tr name="rowID-5">....</tr>`

You can retrieve this value through the use of **jQuery.**

A sample script would be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('tr').on('click', function() {
        //this should store "rowID-5" to the variable id_string
        var id_string = $(this).attr('name');
        //this should just store "5" to the variable id
        var id = id_string.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
    });
});
```